# How to fetch the latest Email received in a particular Email id through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Its possible to build regex to search in Reverse order the Oldest email and a particular value of a thread in Jmeter.I am trying to fetch the latest email sent on my gmail test account, basically in my application it is mandatory to put verification code rec. in your email account for completion of registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i had to pick the last matched value in regex, i use the following technique
Set RegEx match no. to -1 (so that it will fetch all possible match values)
Add a BeanShell postprocessor next to RegEx postprocessor
In BeanShell postprocessor add forllowing code

```
int lstMathchNr = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("regVal_matchNr"));
String tempStr= "regVal_" + lstMathchNr;
String lstMatchVal = vars.get(tempStr);
vars.put("regExVal", lstMatchVal);
```

Now JMeter variable regExVal will have the last matched value